# Need Help with HTTPClient.h and storing cookies

Tags: esp32

Im very new to Arduino. Using an ESP32, Im trying to login to a network device to read its log file. To login to the device I need to simulate a web browser with cookies.

The ESP32 is connecting to WiFI correctly, and Im including the HTTPClient.h file

Using http.begin I am able to browse to the device login page, but I dont know how to store the successful login in a cookie.
From doing some research I think that cookies are just HTTP headers, but I'm not really sure how to read/parse/resend the cookie header in another HTTP request.

I can successfully do it in PEARL using CURL (my code is below). Can someone help me port this to ESP32

```
use strict qw/refs/;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw/POST GET/;

my $Browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(
cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new,
requests_redirectable => ,
timeout => 10,
pragma => "no-cache",
max-age => 0,
agent => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
);

my $Page = $Browser->request(GET $Authenticate);
```

Comment: already posted at https://forum.arduino.cc/t/need-help-with-httpclient-h-and-storing-cookies/924772